# fetch data and update vs saveOrUpdate in hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

I want to update a column in the database. So which one is better having a concept of performance in mind.

1. Fetch data from the database and then set a field using pojo and the use saveOrUpdate method of hibernate.
2. Directly update data by writing update query in hql.

I am asking this because in 1 case there are two hit on database one fetching data and second is saving data and in second case only hitting data in saving value in data base

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say measure... Is the additional programming effort worth the hassle. Do you really want to write update statements (then why do we use ORM tools?!) ... Instead of getting the object you could get a proxy (instead of get use load) and modify/store that.

Comment: getting values from database is done by some other developer and he wrote query to get values which I cannot change.

Comment: Why write a query if you have an ORM tool?! What is the use of the ORM tool then. But still measure and decide if it is worth the additional programming effort to create, maintain all those update statements.

Comment: As I mentioned, measure... Measure the difference (if any) and then decide if it is worth the additional maintenance burden (because you are now basically working around your ORM tool).